# Replace function in select query

Tags: sql, salesforce, str-replace, soql, sfdc

I have double quotes inside some columns as mentioned in the below screenshot.

[image]

How can I apply replace function in the select query to replace double quotes? While I gave replace function, it is throwing the below error.

[image]

Version is `49.0`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your query looks correct.  Perhaps you have a bad hidden character in the query string somehow.

Comment: No bad hidden character. I checked with various combinations. FYI... This is SOQL query (Salesforce). Generally SOQL query doesn't support some syntax. I was checking if what is the alternate solution in SOQL @GordonLinoff

Comment: @SarahAveanavu . . . Wow.  `REPLACE()` is pretty basic functions that *ever* MS Access supports.  But:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/how-to-use-replace-function-in-salesforce-soap-api-in-c.

Comment: Right. SOQL should at least support these kind of basic functions :( @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

SOQL, fundamentally, is not SQL. It does not support a wide variety of features offered by SQL, including the `REPLACE()` function; field aliasing is also not available in SOQL other than in aggregate queries and a handful of supported functions.

SOQL `SELECT` syntax is documented in the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm). Available functions include [aggregation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm), [localization of select elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm), [`FORMAT()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm), a small suite of [date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm), and [currency conversion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) in multicurrency orgs only. However, no general-purpose text manipulation functions are available. This objective must be achieved in Apex or at the API-based client.